# Denial- Why not in American Courts?

Tags: plot-explanation, denial

In the movie *Denial* David Irving subpoenas Deborah Lipstadt to the British courts not the American courts. How does that work?

Is she forced to attend/pay a settlement?

Comment: Probably because libel is easier to prove in English law than American law.  How does that work?  Probably because Lipstadt published also her book in the UK, and under English law she has to prove she was innocent rather than him proving that she wasn't.

Comment: Well I kinda understand why Irving would want that. But is Lipstadt forced to respond? Can people just subpoena people to court in other countries?

Comment: Are you sure it's a subpoena? Is it referred as such in the movie?

Comment: I'm wondering if this might be better over on [Law Exchange](http://law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: She wasn't subpoena'd .... she was sued.  If she offers no defence - then she's guilty of libel.

Comment: One can just sue people in different countries?

Comment: @iandotkelly are you suggesting that had she not had her books published in Britain she wouldn't be forced to go defend her case in the British courts

Comment: I don't know enough about the specific case - but in general in English defamation law the details of the publication of a libel affects how damaging the defamation is - so publishing her book in the UK would certainly have been an consideration.  Libel tourism has certainly been a thing in the English courts because the burden of proof is on the defendent (Lipstadt) not the person bringing the case.

Comment: Irving sued Penguin books Lipstadts UK publisher primarily with Lipstadt as a co-defendant, had the case been won by Irving then damages  would have found been against the publishers and its  profits.